# Can method visibility be inherited in ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, methods

Consider the following example in `Ruby`:

```
class ParentClass
  private def method
    puts "private method"
  end
end

class ChildClass < ParentClass
  def method
    puts "overridden, but should be private too"
  end
end

ParentClass.new.method #=> raises exception
ChildClass.new.method  #=> produces "overridden, but should be private too"
```

If I have no control over the code of `ChildClass`, is it possible to make it inherit method visibility from `ParentClass`?

Comment: Question: If you have no control over ChildClass, why do you need to ensure that the method is private? Maybe they want it to be public after all?

Comment: To find bugs in the program. I mean there are certainly other ways, but I was curious if it's possible! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with inheritance. What is relevant here is the timing of the class method `private`. See the simplified example below. When called, this method turns the relavant method existing at that point into a private method.

```
class A
  def foo; "foo1" end
  private :foo
  new.foo # => NoMethodError: private method `foo' called for #<A:0x007f321204fec0>
end
```

When you alter the method after `private` has applied, then a new method is defined with the same name, and the effect of `private` that applied to the previous definition is gone.

```
class A
  def foo; "foo2" end
  new.foo # => "foo2"
end
```

When you call `private` again on it, then it becomes private:

```
class A
  private :foo
  new.foo # => NoMethodError: private method `foo' called for #<A:0x007f3211ff6de8>
end
```

To illustrate this using your original example...

```
class ChildClass 
  private :method
end
```

... can be done after the initial definition of ChildClass and will make the `method` method private.

To summarize, visibility is a property of a (defined) method, not a property of a method name. So you cannot redefine a method but have the private status of a previous method with the same name but you can change the private status of the current method.

Answer (score 1):

All objects, first prefer to their *own* defined methods, even if their *parent* classes has also the *same named method*. But if you really want in some ocaasion, to call the *parent* class method, then you can take a *help* from `#class_eval` for the same :

```
class ParentClass
  private
  def biz
    puts "private method"
  end
end

class ChildClass < ParentClass
  def biz
    puts "overridden, but should be private too"
  end
end

ChildClass.class_eval do
  remove_method :biz
  self.new.biz
end
# private method `biz' called for #<ChildClass:0x8c3532c> (NoMethodError)
```

Now, see `ChildClass` object is calling the *private* method from the `ParentClass`. Now to make the call successful, you need to use `#send`.

```
ChildClass.class_eval do
  remove_method :biz
  self.new.send :biz # => private method
end
```

Another way, I used in most cases is :-

```
unbind = ParentClass.instance_method(:biz)
unbind.bind(ChildClass.new).call # => private method
```

Really, when you do *inherit* or *mixin*, whatever methods are not physically don't come in to the child or mixed in class respectively. They(parent class or mixed in module) are actually added to the [*method lookup*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) chain of the class `ChildClass`.